# Exceptions handle in PHP

Tags: php, exception

I try throw exception when there is no result in database, here is code:

```
try {
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
       throw new ErrorExeption('there is no row with that id');
    }
} catch (ErrorExeption $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

So, when I paste wron Id I cant see the error message. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `execute` will only return `false` if there's an error. If it there are no matches it will return `true`, but the first attempt to fetch a row will return `false`.

Comment: I think you might want to change 'execute' to 'fetch' because this is when you'll actually know if there are any rows or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this:

```
try {
    $stmt->execute();

    if (!$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        throw new ErrorExeption('there is no row with that id');
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (ErrorExeption $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please consider to check the spelling on `ErrorExeption` to `ErrorException` ?

Because I tried this on my local server, and the script can catch error message that we throw above.